# ffmpeg: avcodec_open2 returns invalid argument

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm reusing the sample code from the developer 64-bit release of FFmpeg in my application to encode a video:

```cpp
AVCodec* pCodec_{nullptr};
AVCodecContext* pContext_{nullptr};

avcodec_register_all();
pCodec_ = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
if (!pCodec_) {}

pContext_ = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec_);
if (!pContext_) {}

pContext_->bit_rate = 400000;
pContext_->width = size.width();
pContext_->height = size.height();

pContext_->time_base.den = 1;
pContext_->time_base.num = fps;

pContext_->gop_size = 10;
pContext_->max_b_frames = 1;
pContext_->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_BGR0;

if (codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
    av_opt_set(pContext_->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
}

int err = avcodec_open2(pContext_, pCodec_, nullptr);
if (err < 0) {}
```

`AVCodec*` and `AVCodecContext*` look like they are allocated correctly. `avcodec_open2` then returns invalid argument (`-22`).

I use: Windows 10 64, VS2013 Compiler, Qt Creator IDE, ffmpeg(2016-05-12) 64bit.

The sample I took the code from is [decoding_encoding.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2decoding_encoding_8c-example.html).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to set `pContext_->codec_type = 1; // video`

Comment: the error tells us where to look try setting `pContext->sample_fmt` try this this with all available values as of ffmpeg 4.2.4 there are less then 15 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some Ideas:

- look at this: [FFMPEG - format not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564870/ffmpeg-format-not-available) seems that ffpmeg expects you to set a pix_fmt which is natively supported by the encoder.
- Your time base seems odd. I guess it should be 1/fps, not fps/1
- Play with the bit rate. I vaguely remember that, at least some years ago, this value was expected to be in kbit/s of bit/s, depending on the codec. (Also 400 kbit/s is quite low for mpeg2, but it should still work, I guess).
- for a first test, use standard resolutions like 720 × 480. IIRC mpeg2 only supports certain resolutions, at least both dimensions have to be multiples of 8.

Comment: it was the resolution - 720x480 works .. Thank you .. (i also changed the other values u recommended)