# avcodec_open2 returns Invalid Argument (errnum -22)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode a vector of AVFrames to an MP4 file using the h264 codec.

Everything seems to work fine until the avcodec_open2 function, which returns an "Invalid Argument" (-22) error.

*The stream parameter is a pointer to AVStream.

Here is the code that sets the stream parameters:

```
    stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    stream->codecpar->width = settings.resolution[0]; // 270
    stream->codecpar->height = settings.resolution[1]; // 480
    stream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    stream->codecpar->bit_rate = 400000;
    AVRational framerate = { 1, 30};
    stream->time_base = av_inv_q(framerate);
```

And here is the code that opens the codec context:

```
    // Open the codec context
    AVCodecContext* codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codec_ctx) {
        std::cout << "Error allocating codec context" << std::endl;
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << "Error setting codec context parameters: " << av_err2str(ret) << std::endl;
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }

    ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        wxMessageBox("Error opening codec: ");
        wxMessageBox(av_err2str(ret));
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        avformat_free_context(format_ctx);
        return;
    }
```

I tried the solution that [@philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/664204/philipp) suggested in [ffmpeg-avcodec-open2-returns-invalid-argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185497/ffmpeg-avcodec-open2-returns-invalid-argument) but it didn't resolve my error.

I don't know what's causing this error in my code, can someone please help me?

Comment: How do you get the `codec`, does it come from some thing like `avcodec_find_decoder(xxx)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `codec_ctx->time_base` is uninitialized.

Before executing `ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, nullptr);`, add the following line of code:

```
codec_ctx->time_base = stream->time_base;
```

---

The default value of `codec_ctx->time_base` is `{0, 0}`, and that causes `avcodec_open2` to return an error status.

Note that executing `avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, stream->codecpar)` doesn't copy the `time_base`, because `time_base` is not part of `stream->codecpar`.

Comment: It wasn't so simple to find... Next time you post a question, please post a code sample that we can build and execute - it's going to be much easier to find the issue.