# avcodec_open2 returns -22 "Invalid argument" trying to encode AV_CODEC_ID_H264

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, libavcodec

I'm trying to use libavcodec to encode h264 video but avcodec_open2 returns -22 "Invalid argument" and I can't figure out why. Here is my code, which is mostly a copy from the encode example from libavcodec.

```
    /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
    const AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", "h.264");
        exit(1);
    }

    AVCodecContext* codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecContext) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);

    /* put sample parameters */
    codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    codecContext->width = 1920;
    codecContext->height = 1080;
    /* frames per second */
    codecContext->time_base = { 1, 25 };
    codecContext->framerate = { 25, 1 };

    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    codecContext->gop_size = 10;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    codecContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "profile", "baseline", 0);

    /* open it */
    int ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, nullptr);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char eb[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec: %s\n", av_make_error_string(eb, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, ret));
        exit(1);
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: MPEG1/2/4 work, I'm just not sure what's missing for h.264.

Comment: Sounds very similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185497/ffmpeg-avcodec-open2-returns-invalid-argument. I would check out the suggested solutions for that

Comment: I've already checked all that. It seems to be something with the fact that it's using h264_mf instead of libx264, and there is some parameter missing that I dont know about.

Comment: I added a logger, and thi message is logged:
Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'baseline'

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for "h264_mf" codec you need a capital "B" in "Baseline".